# Integral action or correction factor on disturbance?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I wonder what's the difference between having a integral action or correction factor when it comes to disturbances?

Ofc I know how to apply then, the reason for this question is: What's suits best for disturbances?

Assume that we got a system discribed as a transer function $G(s)$ LTV system and we have a controller $K(s)$.

The feedback loop will then be:

$$G_f (s) = \frac{K(s)G(s)}{1+K(s)G(s)}$$

Assume that our reference value $r(t)$ should be the same as output value $y(t)$, but it isin't! There is a error between $r(t)$ and $y(t)$.

$$y(t) = G_f(s)r(t)$$

To solve this I just add a constant after reference $r(t)$.

$$y(t) = G_f(s)\frac{1}{G_f(0)}r(t)$$

$\frac{1}{G_f(0)}$ is called the low gain frequency. A correction factor for $r(t)$ so $r(t) = y(t)$

**Question:**

What do you recomend: Correction factor for $r(t)$ if we can estimate the system $G(s)$ over time, or integral action when it comes to small disturbances?

Comment: Since G ia LTV does that also mean you would change $1/G_f(0)$ with time as well?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes! I got this wondering today at the work. What if I replace integral action with low frequency gain at the reference point? How would that be? The low frequency gain is ment to give a better tracking and so do integral action too. But how would the both act with small disturbances? If it does not matter if I use low frequency gain or integral action, then I think I will chose low frequency gain factor beacuse the model can be estimated. Also, integral action needs tuning too.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen What do you think? Estimation + low frequency gain on reference would be better that integral action? The bad thing with integral action is anti-winup is required.